# cascading 4 level dropdown list php

Tags: php, jquery, html, drop-down-menu, cascading

I am newly developing a php site and I need help to implement 4 level cascading dropdown list:

Eg:

`1st dropdown: State`
`2nd dropdown: District`
`3rd dropdown: Mandal`
`4th dropdown: Village`

On successful selection of village dropdown: the data in that particular table should be presented on the new page. Hope you understood my requirement.

Comment: What have you tried? We are not here to build scripts for you. We are here to help you build script. Please provide us with the code you created and problems you encounter with this code.